# Append from dynamic temp table

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

This question might have been asked before, but I've spent considerable time looking for an answer withouth success... Because I'm quite new at this, the answer might be there, but I fail to identify it.

I get raw data in csv showing me the times our agents spent on certain statuses (break, email, meeting, lunch, ...). There will be a column for each status.

I import this csv into a temporary tabel in access, which I append to the master table. I have to do this several times a day.

The problem is, that in the morning, if none of the agents went on the lunch status, the column will not be in the csv file.The columns will only be there if they are used. Thus, when I try to append it, it will give an error and ask for a parameter value for that column.

this is the append code in access:

```
INSERT INTO T0_Reason_codes ( [DATE], AGENT, [AGENT FIRST NAME], [AGENT LAST NAME], [AGENT EMAIL], [HOUR], [Break / AGENT STATE TIME], [Casenotes / AGENT STATE TIME], [Email / AGENT STATE TIME], [Lunch / AGENT STATE TIME], [Project / AGENT STATE TIME], [Remote Session / AGENT STATE TIME], [Training / AGENT STATE TIME] )

SELECT Q0_Reason_Codes.DATE, Q0_Reason_Codes.AGENT, Q0_Reason_Codes.[AGENT FIRST NAME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[AGENT LAST NAME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[AGENT EMAIL], Q0_Reason_Codes.HOUR, Q0_Reason_codes.[Break / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[Casenotes / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[Email / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_codes.[Lunch / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[Project / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_codes.[Remote Session / AGENT STATE TIME], Q0_Reason_Codes.[Training / AGENT STATE TIME]

FROM Q0_Reason_Codes LEFT JOIN T0_Reason_codes ON (Q0_Reason_Codes.[date] = T0_Reason_codes.[date]) AND (Q0_Reason_Codes.[hour] = T0_Reason_codes.[hour]) AND (Q0_Reason_Codes.[agent] = T0_Reason_codes.[agent])

WHERE (((([T0_reason_codes].[date] Is Null) And [T0_Reason_codes].[agent] Is Null And [T0_Reason_codes].[hour]) Is Null));
```

The only workaround I can think of is, in excel write a script that checks if the column exists and create it if it does not.

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: The idea to write a script is valid, but why in Excel, and not in Access? You could check in Access if a certain column exists, and import it if it does.

Comment: Because i'm more comfortable with excel :) Though, I can imagine it being  more efficient in access. How would I go about it in access?

Comment: VBA is VBA, Access and Excel VBA aren't that different. The pseudocode would just be: check if a column exists, if so, execute the query, if not, don't. You could even execute the import in the same query. But you will have to be specific about which part of this is difficult for you.

Comment: I can see that I need to check if the column exists, but if it does not exist, it would need to create it, or skip it. So I guess I would use a function to check if the field exists, like the one on [link](http://software-solutions-online.com/check-if-field-exists-vba-access/), and create the field if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, you can just add fields to tables (either through `ADO` and `DDL`, which is the same technique your link uses to check if the field exists, or using `TableDefs`). Then you can run the full import.

Comment: Great, works like a charm! Thx Erik